# SSIS Refesh Excel with no office installed in server

Tags: excel, ssis, ms-office

As explained [here](http://jessicammoss.blogspot.co.il/2008/10/manipulating-excel-spreadsheets-in-ssis.html), it is easy to refresh excel from task script.
Since we don't have office in our server, is it possible to do the above without having office installed in the server?

I need to automate process of sending once a week, 2 excel sheets.1-data based on sql query.2-pivot that based on 1. The problem is that I can't use ssrs and ssas for a solution and IT have good reasons not to install office on the sql server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This bit of code requires Excel to be installed:

```
Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
```

If you describe your issue more extensively maybe we can help further.

To load an Excel sheet with data you can either push it in (i.e. from SSIS), in which case you don't necessarily need Excel installed.

To automatically generate a pivot in Excel, you probably do need Excel installed.

Since this Excel sheet is eventually delivered to a user, why can't the user run macros inside an Excel sheet to pull back the data and generate the pivot? Alternatively you could automatically generate all of this on a server which does have Excel installed.

Comment: I need to automate process of sending once a week, 2 excel sheets.1-data based on sql query.2-pivot that based on 1. The problem is that I can't use ssrs and ssas for a solution and IT have good reasons not to install office on the sql server...